# How to use setters in Spring

Tags: java, spring, scope

I've realised that refferencing an instance of a spring bean of scope `@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "prototype")` seems to call a new instance of the bean whenever the same instance gets referenced.

For example:

```
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "prototype")
class Item {

    .....
}

@Component
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "prototype")
class A {

    private Item item;

    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public void method() {
        item.doSomething();
    }

}

@Component
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "prototype")
class B {

    @Autowired
    private A a;

    @Autowired
    private Item item;

    void bMethod() {
        a.setItem(item);
        a.method();
    }
}
```

The instance of `A` in `a.setItem(item);` seems to be different from that in `a.method();`, thereby making it imposible to use accessor methods in beans with scope of `@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "prototype")`.

Is this an expected behaviour? Am I missing some understanding on the usage of `@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "prototype")`?

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `proxyMode` on your `A` bean. With a `proxyMode` of `TARGET_CLASS`, the bean is actually a proxy which delegates any method invocation to a new instance.